# iOS 7 dynamic blur effect like in Control Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, blur, ios7

I'm trying to make a controller that will be similar to Control Center in iOS7. From WWDC session #226 I've learnt how to get blurred image with different effects

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NULL, 0);

[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lightImage = [newImage applyLightEffect];
```

So, in other words, we just capture some image (make screenshot), perform blur effect and use this blurred image for our needs.

But if you open control center above some dynamic content you'll notice that control center's blurred background is changing as well as content does.

Does anybody know how to replicate this behavior?

The only way I see it is to capture content and make blur effect with some interval (e.g. half a second). But it looks redundantly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here are ready solutions that I've found:

**1. The most unexpected: Use UIToolBar**

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder]))
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setup
{
    if (iOS7OrLater)
    {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        toolbar.barTintColor = self.tintColor;
        [self insertSubview:toolbar atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

UIToolbar can be used for this needs, bacuse it has his only build-in blur mechanism, and this mechanism is dynamic, what is good. But the bad thing is that in some reason it ignores colors and makes background looks irredeemably...

[image: Toolbar effect]

**Update:**

To avoid color breaking, do not use barTintColor. You also may change style of toolbar if you want dark styled blur (use UIBarStyleBlack).

**2. [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).**

Unlike toolbar it more positive, but it's dynamic mechanism is rare yet and in fact it can be used only for static background. (dynamic = NO).

[image: FBBlurView effect]

Comment: When you set a tintColor, blur breaks. Just use a default toolbar or the one with dark barStyle. And please don't use an FXBlurView in dynamic mode because it will drain users' batteries faster than it can render blur.

Comment: Thanks, @FilipRadelic! As you said, I removed tintColor and set UIBarStyleBlack for toolbar. It's dynamic and now looks almost perfect :). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Any ideas if this type of implementation will result in getting rejected by apple? Or on the contrary, will they celebrate the creative approach?

Comment: If you are not using private API's or violating UI guide lines, they won't reject

Comment: If you want more control and real-time animation, ypu can use this sublcass of UIView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19506076/774394.

Comment: I managed to achieve some very cool effects using the toolbar approach. Thanks!

Comment: You can set semitransparent background color for your view and put toolbar on top, will at least let you saturate its blur.

Comment: Instead of using the full bar you could just use the toolbar layer... add the toolbar layer as a sublayer of your view.

Comment: ie:  [self.blurView.layer addSublayer:self.toolBar.layer] (you need to retain the uitoolbar as a property to be sure to keep it around..)

Comment: the idea of the blur effect is to have transparency to see what happens in the controller that is in the background. FXBlurView not working as expected because the controller completely paralyzed background

Answer (score 13):

In iOS8 we can implement blur effect on views using [UIVisualEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIVisualEffect) class.

Answer (score 8):

You can use below code to apply blur effect on view.

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

visualEffectView.frame = MYview.bounds;
[MYview addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found LiveFrost to be a great, and easy to integrate project for live blurring.

https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost/

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIVisualEffect from storyboard.

Drag the Visual Effect With Blur on the storyboard. The desired effect can be achieved by setting alpha of the BACKGROUND COLOR. The subviews should be added to View of Visual Effect View and they are not affected by the background blur.

The Vibrancy effect must be selected in View options above.

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using navigation bar to provide blurring will not work on older devices running iOS 7. As they are running lighter version of iOS 7 with almost no t