# How to implement a real time iOS7 blur effect in the UITableViewCell's background

Tags: ios, ios7

I want the UITableViewCell's background to have an iOS7 blur effect. It's dynamic, means, while the cell is scrolling, its blurred background should change depend on the color below.

I found some relative topics.

[iPhone SDK - Frosted Glass (iOS 7 Blur) Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601166/iphone-sdk-frosted-glass-ios-7-blur-effect).  It introduce GPUImage. It about still image, I didn't figure out how to make a dynamic one.

[iOS 7 dynamic blur effect like in Control Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704240/ios-7-dynamic-blur-effect-like-in-control-center). It use UIToolbar as the background of cell, taking advantage of system built-in blur effect. It works great, but just the transparency is a little low. I have adjusted the alpha of tool bar, but it doesn't ideal.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like you said, there is possibility to use UIToolbar to get real-time blur. Here is a little class to get desired modification of appearance:

https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView

Comment: Will this get approved by Apple?