# iOS Blur Background like iTunes Remote App

Tags: ios, text, background, mask, blur

I'm new here so please bear with me. 
Can you please help me make a transparent blured background like the one used in iTunes Remote iOS7 app in the store? Also, how is the text masked?
Screenshot here: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [rackcdn.com](http://313e5987718b346aaf83-f5e825270f29a84f7881423410384342.r78.cf1.rackcdn.com/1383617171-2013-11-05_03.05.58_01.jpeg))</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262199/how-to-implement-a-real-time-ios7-blur-effect-in-the-uitableviewcells-backgroun

Hope it's what you need.

Comment: What about the text & controls masking?

Comment: I'm definitely interested in hearing how the text masking works. That's one of the first questions I had when seeing those screenshots.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK - Frosted Glass (iOS 7 Blur) Effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601166/iphone-sdk-frosted-glass-ios-7-blur-effect)

Comment: @paulrehkugler it's not quite a mask. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the "UIImage+ImageEffect" class made by Apple, in a WWDC example Apple posted here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013#. 
Using this class, is's really simple to blur an image with this code: *[image applyLightEffect]* 
where image as an instance of UIImage.

Here are the steps i took to make the text look like it's "cut" from the background view. Use this layering order:

1. Blurred Image
2. View with lower opacity (ex 80%) filled with a color. I used a white background color. 
   2.1. Set a label as a child of this view and set the tint color to Black.
3. Add any other content you want on top.

And voila! It magically works!

Comment: I don't understand your layering solution. Could you add a code snippet or something?

Comment: If you could please attach code/github illustrating this effect that would be great!

Comment: How can I make the same for UIView instead UIImage?

Comment: Xcode 6 offers Visual Effect View with Blur. You can find it in Object Library

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIToolBar` of UIKit framework which automatically comes with blur and transparent effect on background view (live).

**Reason** - Since `UIToolBar` inherits `UIView` so fundamentally there is no issue in using it in place of UIView.