# In Objective-C, is there a native way to create the blur-ish effect like the control center?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

I am looking for a way to segue to another view controller while keeping the presenting one's view as blurry background. If it is not possible, then, instead of segueing, i will try to add a new subview, as long as it can achieve the blurry background effect.

There is already a package [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) that seems able to achieve this. But I wonder if this can be done using latest Xcode? Thanks!

Comment: The most popular hack seems to be to add a toolBar programmatically with the required frame-size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 dynamic blur effect like in Control Center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704240/ios-7-dynamic-blur-effect-like-in-control-center)