# Improve Blur Performance iOS7/8

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, ios7, blur

Is this the quickest way to blur a view - because for my view (UICollectionView of images) it's too slow for good UX - any tips on performance improvements, better methods?

I tried altering the scale on the BeginImageContext method (third variable), with little change in performance.

```
(import category on UIImage from Apple)
#UIImage+ImageEffects.h 

- (UIImage*)blurViewToImage:(UIView *)view type:(int)type {

//0 -dark
//1 -light
//2 -extra light

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, true, 0.0f);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:false];
UIImage * snappy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

switch (type) {
    case 0:
        return [snappy applyDarkEffect];
        break;
    case 1:
        return [snappy applyLightEffect];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [snappy applyExtraLightEffect];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704240/ios-7-dynamic-blur-effect-like-in-control-center?rq=1)

If this won't suit your needs try to call the function

```
- (UIImage*)blurViewToImage:(UIView *)view type:(int)type
```

in a separate Thread, so your UI keeps usable:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:(SEL) withObject:(id)]
```

Comment: thanks - I'd normally run it on a background thread but then it'd take longer, plus the background can change but is static when the user calls it, so I can't preload images either. It's funny that the best solution is to trick UIToolbar into being a background. At least with iOS8 we get more power.