# adding a layer mask to UIToolBar/UINavigationBar/UITabBar breaks translucency

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

Im upgrading my UI to iOS 7, and have been using a custom tab bar which has a CAShapeLayer used as a mask. Ive been trying to add dynamic blur by having a UIToolBar underneath, but if i try setting the layer.mask property on the toolbar translucency is gone, and i just have it semi transparent (but masking works of course). Is there a way to get this working? Ive also seen this behavior when adding a subview to these classes.

Comment: I've met this problem,do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

If "translucency is gone" means it becomes totally transparent and if you tested just on simulator, it is a known bug of simulator. If you run it on devices, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue. My solution isn't ideal, but it will work in all cases that don't need a dynamic background. After reading the following comment in, [How can I produce an effect similar to the iOS 7 blur view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view/18142035#comment28564074_18142035). I realized that trying to find a way to alter the toolbar will get me nowhere. So lets use an image!

In [Apples Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) site you can search for `ImageEffects` and find the code we're going to be using. It comes with the iOS 8 blur effects your familiar with, `Light`, `ExtraLight` and `Dark`.

Here's the .h file with our own class extension at the bottom to make things a bit easier.

```
/*
 File: UIImage+ImageEffects.h
 Abstract: This is a category of UIImage that adds methods to apply blur and tint effects to an image. This is the code you’ll want to look out to find out how to use vImage to efficiently calculate a blur.
  Version: 1.0

 Disclaimer: IMPORTANT:  This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple
 Inc. ("Apple") in consideration of your agreement to the following
 terms, and your use, installation, modification or redistribution of
 this Apple software constitutes acceptance of these terms.  If you do
 not agree with these terms, please do not use, install, modify or
 redistribute this Apple software.

 In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
 subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive
 license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the
 "Apple Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
 Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;
 provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
 without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following
 text and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software.
 Neither the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may
 be used to endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software
 without specific prior written permission from Apple.  Except as
 expressly stated in this notice, no other rights or licenses, express or
 implied, are granted by Apple herein, including but not limited to any
 patent rights that may be infringed by your derivative works or by other
 works in which the Apple Software may be incorporated.

 The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis.  APPLE
 MAKES NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION
 THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND
 OPERATION ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.

 IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL
 OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 INTERRUPTION) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION,
 MODIFICATION AND/OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED
 AND WHETHER UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE),
 STRICT LIABILITY OR OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 Copyright (C) 2013 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.


 Copyright © 2013 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 WWDC 2013 License

 NOTE: This Apple Software was supplied by Apple as part of a WWDC 2013
 Session. Please refer to the applicable WWDC 2013 Session for further
 information.

 IMPORTANT: This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple Inc.
 ("Apple") in consideration of your agreement to the following terms, and
 your use, installation, modification or redistribution of this Apple
 software constitutes acceptance of these terms. If you do not agree with
 these terms, please do not use, install, modify or redistribute this
 Apple software.

 In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
 subject to these terms, Apple grants you a non-exclusive license, under
 Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the "Apple
 Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
 Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;
 provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
 without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following
 text and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software.
 Neither the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may
 be used to endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software
 without specific prior written permission from Apple. Except as
 expressly stated in this notice, no other rights or licenses, express or
 implied, are granted by Apple herein, including but not limited to any
 patent rights that may be infringed by your derivative works or by other
 works in which the Apple Software may be incorporated.

 The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis. APPLE MAKES
 NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION THE
 IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND
 OPERATION ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.

 IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL
 OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 INTERRUPTION) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION,
 MODIFICATION AND/OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED
 AND WHETHER UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE),
 STRICT LIABILITY OR OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 EA1002
 5/3/2013
 */

@import UIKit;

@interface UIImage (ImageEffects)

- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage;

@end

@interface UIView (MyImageEffects)

- (UIImage *)lightBlurredSnapshot;
- (UIImage *)extraLightBlurredSnapshot;
- (UIImage *)darkBlurredSnapshot;
- (UIImage *)blurredSnapshotWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

@end
```

And the .m file.

```
/*
 File: UIImage+ImageEffects.m
 Abstract: This is a category of UIImage that adds methods to apply blur and tint effects to an image. This is the code you’ll want to look out to find out how to use vImage to efficiently calculate a blur.
  Version: 1.0

 Disclaimer: IMPORTANT:  This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple
 Inc. ("Apple") in consideration of your agreement to the following
 terms, and your use, installation, modification or redistribution of
 this Apple software constitutes acceptance of these terms.  If you do
 not agree with these terms, please do not use, install, modify or
 redistribute this Apple software.

 In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
 subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive
 license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the
 "Apple Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
 Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;
 provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
 without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following
 text and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software.
 Neither the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may
 be used to endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software
 without specific prior written permission from Apple.  Except as
 expressly stated in this notice, no other rights or licenses, express or
 implied, are granted by Apple herein, including but not limited to any
 patent rights that may be infringed by your derivative works or by other
 works in which the Apple Software may be incorporated.

 The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis.  APPLE
 MAKES NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION
 THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND
 OPERATION ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.

 IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL
 OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 INTERRUPTION) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION,
 MODIFICATION AND/OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED
 AND WHETHER UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE),
 STRICT LIABILITY OR OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 Copyright (C) 2013 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.


 Copyright © 2013 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 WWDC 2013 License

 NOTE: This Apple Software was supplied by Apple as part of a WWDC 2013
 Session. Please refer to the applicable WWDC 2013 Session for further
 information.

 IMPORTANT: This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple Inc.
 ("Apple") in consideration of your agreement to the following terms, and
 your use, installation, modification or redistribution of this Apple
 software constitutes acceptance of these terms. If you do not agree with
 these terms, please do not use, install, modify or redistribute this
 Apple software.

 In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
 subject to these terms, Apple grants you a non-exclusive license, under
 Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the "Apple
 Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
 Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;
 provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
 without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following
 text and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software.
 Neither the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may
 be used to endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software
 without specific prior written permission from Apple. Except as
 expressly stated in this notice, no other rights or licenses, express or
 implied, are granted by Apple herein, including but not limited to any
 patent rights that may be infringed by your derivative works or by other
 works in which the Apple Software may be incorporated.

 The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis. APPLE MAKES
 NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION THE
 IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF NON-INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND
 OPERATION ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.

 IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL
 OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 INTERRUPTION) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION,
 MODIFICATION AND/OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED
 AND WHETHER UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE),
 STRICT LIABILITY OR OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 EA1002
 5/3/2013
 */

#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h"

@import Accelerate;
#import <float.h>

//  Shared Singletons
#import "AppearanceManager.h"


@implementation UIImage (ImageEffects)


- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:30 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:0.82];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:20 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.11 alpha:0.73];
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:20 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    const CGFloat EffectColorAlpha = 0.6;
    UIColor *effectColor = tintColor;
    int componentCount = (int)CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(tintColor.CGColor);
    if (componentCount == 2) {
        CGFloat b;
        if ([tintColor getWhite:&b alpha:NULL]) {
            effectColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:b alpha:EffectColorAlpha];
        }
    }
    else {
        CGFloat r, g, b;
        if ([tintColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:NULL]) {
            effectColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:EffectColorAlpha];
        }
    }
    return [self applyBlurWithRadius:10 tintColor:effectColor saturationDeltaFactor:-1.0 maskImage:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    // Check pre-conditions.
    if (self.size.width < 1 || self.size.height < 1) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: invalid size: (%.2f x %.2f). Both dimensions must be >= 1: %@", self.size.width, self.size.height, self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!self.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: %@", self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (maskImage && !maskImage.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: %@", maskImage);
        return nil;
    }

    CGRect imageRect = { CGPointZero, self.size };
    UIImage *effectImage = self;

    BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    BOOL hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.) > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    if (hasBlur || hasSaturationChange) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(effectInContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(effectInContext, 0, -self.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(effectInContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

        vImage_Buffer effectInBuffer;
        effectInBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;
        effectOutBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectOutContext);

        if (hasBlur) {
            // A description of how to compute the box kernel width from the Gaussian
            // radius (aka standard deviation) appears in the SVG spec:
            // http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement
            // 
            // For larger values of 's' (s >= 2.0), an approximation can be used: Three
            // successive box-blurs build a piece-wise quadratic convolution kernel, which
            // approximates the Gaussian kernel to within roughly 3%.
            //
            // let d = floor(s * 3*sqrt(2*pi)/4 + 0.5)
            // 
            // ... if d is odd, use three box-blurs of size 'd', centered on the output pixel.
            // 
            CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            unsigned int radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if (radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
            }
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
        }
        BOOL effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = NO;
        if (hasSaturationChange) {
            CGFloat s = saturationDeltaFactor;
            CGFloat floatingPointSaturationMatrix[] = {
                0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                                  0,                    0,                    0,  1,
            };
            const int32_t divisor = 256;
            NSUInteger matrixSize = sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix)/sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[0]);
            int16_t saturationMatrix[matrixSize];
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
                saturationMatrix[i] = (int16_t)roundf(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor);
            }
            if (hasBlur) {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
                effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = YES;
            }
            else {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
            }
        }
        if (!effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if (effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    // Set up output context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.size.height);

    // Draw base image.
    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

    // Draw effect image.
    if (hasBlur) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        if (maskImage) {
            CGContextClipToMask(outputContext, imageRect, maskImage.CGImage);
        }
        CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, effectImage.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Add in color tint.
    if (tintColor) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Output image is ready.
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}


@end

@implementation UIView (MyImageEffects)

- (UIImage *)lightBlurredSnapshot {
    return [self blurredSnapshotWithImage:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
        return [image applyLightEffect];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)extraLightBlurredSnapshot {
    return [self blurredSnapshotWithImage:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
        return [image applyExtraLightEffect];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)darkBlurredSnapshot {
    return [self blurredSnapshotWithImage:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
        return [image applyDarkEffect];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)blurredSnapshotWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor {
    return [self blurredSnapshotWithImage:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
        return [image applyTintEffectWithColor:tintColor];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)blurredSnapshotWithImage:(UIImage *(^)(UIImage* image))imageBlock {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    UIImage* blurredSnapshotImage = imageBlock(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext());

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return blurredSnapshotImage;
}

@end
```

Now you can simply import the header and call something like this.

```
UIImage* image = [self.view lightBlurredSnapshot];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Apply your mask to the layer and you're good to go!

Comment: Why did you post the sources here instead of just linking to them?

Comment: @LeoNatan 1) Not everyone has an Apple developer account, which is needed to download Apple code. 2) If the code were to be removed from Apples site, it would still exist here. 3) The custom code only makes sense after reading Apples .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need [AMDraggableBlurView](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMDraggableBlurView).