# Blurry transparent view over UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I want to show a static view above a UITableView.
The static view should be a little transparent, blurring what's underneath it (much like the new iOS7 control center).

The effect should look like this:
[image]

Notic that the since the transparent view will not cover the whole screen, the UITableView should still be scrollable and so the blurry background would change.

How can I achieve that effect?
I'm trying to avoid using the solution given here:
[How can I produce an effect similar to the iOS 7 blur view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view)

Comment: The question you linked to is a pretty thorough catalog of possible ways to get this effect. Which of those have you tried and found inadequate?

Comment: I have tried the toolbar method - but I'm afraid apple will not approve the app on the app store