# Frost glass effect in android

Tags: android

I want to have frost glass effect in android (commonly available in ios) see the image, i applied gaussian blur effect using code, but didn't getting the desired result,
Please help

[image]

Comment: post your code here..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26270218/185022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out these android library:

https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur

https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign

Comment: Your second link https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign works well, but my listview bubbles donot go behind frost glass, as i shown in image in my question, anyways thanks

Answer (score 2):

<del>have you tried [this library](https://github.com/harism/android_anndblur) it is working same as ios7 blur effect</del>

This library doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I imported this project to eclipse it throws complilation error

Answer (score 2):

Does this help ? http://latest-tutorial.com/2013/10/07/blur-mask-filter-bitmap-android/

I'm also in the hunt for a similar result , hope to test it out soon

Comment: i am not looking for blur mask... i was looking glass frost effect like in ios 7

Comment: novice to as to how glass is achieved , i tried this , i took a image blur'd it in my Photoshop and then added this png to a root layout , then added one more layout with  android:background="#aa000000" to get a blackish glass overlay effect transparent