# How to remove the gray layer under inputView in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, ios7.1, inputview

Ok, here is how my app used to look like in iOS 7.0:

[image]

Now in iOS 7.1 for some reason it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see instead of white blurred background (the greeninsh thing is actually a green `UITextField` underneath) it is now gray blurred background - if you look closely the green is still visible.

After a lot of experimenting I found out that this is because of a gray layer that is beneath the `UIPickerView`. Here is the result when I set the hidden property of the `UIPickerView` to YES:

[image]

The code is pretty simple:

```
_swimlanePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_swimlanePicker.delegate = self;
_swimlanePicker.dataSource = self;
[_swimlanePicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
_swimlaneTextField.inputView = _swimlanePicker;
```

Do you have any ideas how can I hide (or change the color/transparency of) this gray layer?
I liked the old look and want to achieve it in iOS 7.1 too.

Comment: Change the backgroundColor of the view like any other view?

Comment: This hides the blurred views underneath.

Comment: try to change UIPickerView tint color

Comment: As I said - this has nothing to do with the UIPickerView itself - when it is hidden the gray view is still there.

Comment: Have you tried changing the backgroundColor to no color (i.e. alpha 0)?

Comment: Yep. The result is the same as when hidden = YES -> see the last screenshot.

Comment: @AXE Did u ever found its solution?

Comment: Haven't looked more into it, so - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the fact that Apple made changes to the appearance of the keyboard. It's sligtly different in iOS 7.1.

A quote from an [article](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/03/ios-7-1-features.html) presenting changes between the versions (you can see a screenshots with the keyboards before and after).

> Apple has also made subtle changes to the keyboard. The font is
>   slightly more bold. The shift and delete buttons have also been
>   tweaked slightly. The background of the keyboard also seems to be
>   slightly lighter than in iOS 7. It seems to add more contrast and
>   makes the letters easier to see.

So I guess you can't do anything without a really ugly hack, like messing around with the underlying CALayers.

You can read about how to add a translucent layer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view).
A comment from the first approach from the link:

> I ran this approach by an Apple UIKit engineer this week at their Tech
>   Talks lab. While he certainly would not endorse this approach, he
>   recognized the need for the effect and the lack of real public API for
>   this, and said that this approach was the "least evil" option for now
>   and is fairly safe as written. Specifically he said do not try to do
>   any animations of the frame or transform of this toolbar/view or
>   anything like that, or bad things will happen. He also strongly
>   suggested to file Radar bug reports on this, to build a case
>   internally so we can get a real public API for this effect!

Comment: I guess you are right. I'll wait a little while before accepting this as the sad but true answer :D
About the translucent layer - that's what I was using :)

Comment: @AXE Maybe you could report a bug https://bugreport.apple.com. They would probably reject it, but at least you should get an official explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it took me some hours to find a very simple solution.

Basically put the picker in a view with your desired `backgroundColor`. Add this view as your `inputView`. AND: Don't set the textfields `keyboardAppearance` to dark!

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

let datePickerBackground = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:0.0, height:216.0))
datePickerBackground.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
datePickerBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
datePickerBackground.addSubview(datePicker)

let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0))
textField.keyboardAppearance = .Default // Don't set it to .Dark!
textField.inputView = datePickerBackground
addSubview(textField)
```

Comment: For some reason when I try it I still get a gray view.