# How to get blurry dominant image color on like Snapguide

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm looking to achieve an effect like this one in Snapguide:

[image: Snapguide image colors]

They are getting main image color and blurring (not sure, but I looks like they are) it somehow. I think I saw somewhere that there is a similar option available in iOS 8, but I couldn't find it anywhere. So does anyone know how they do it, or how can I get a similar effect?

Also to note, I'm working on new Xcode for iOS 7 & 8 in Swift, but I don't think that matters much.

Comment: Great question and answer.  There's an absurd idea on this site that it's "not good to ask for advice on which package to use" - great QA like this show how silly that idea is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To extract the dominant image color, check out **[ColorArt](https://github.com/panicinc/ColorArt)**.

Once you get the dominant color, try setting the tint color of a `UIVisualEffectView` to the required color. Init the `VisualEffectView` with a `UIBlurEffect`.

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
blur.tintColor = /* yourColor */
blur.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(blur)
```

Comment: I managed to get the desired effect by setting the views background to `ColorArt.primaryColor` and then applying the blur as subview. Thanks!

Comment: This is only for iOS 8 or later!
What about 7?

Comment: @LLIAJLbHOu: ColorArt will work for iOS 7 and below. For getting the blur, you could either implement your own technique or use a 3rd party project like this one: [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView). Also check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view) SO question.

Comment: I take many errors when i copy ColorArt .h and.m files in the project. Why?

Comment: @GabyFitcal Check out this iOS port for ColorArt: https://github.com/vinhnx/ColorArt.

Comment: @aksh1t Setting the tint colour isn't changing the colour of the blur for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For getting effect like the screenshot you can use [DBImageColorPicker](https://github.com/d0ping/DBImageColorPicker).
This component allows getting various kinds of main colors also additional primary text color and secondary text color.