# How to achieve the Blur Effect like apple doing on home screen in iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

[image]

I need to apply the blur effect to my UIViewController as shown in above image, i tried using UIVisualEffectView but the Apple Default BlurEffectStyles doesn't match my current requirement, why because i need to adjust the Blur level to reach my requirement.Above Image is an example to satisfy my requirement.

NOTE: Is Apple also apply the UIVisualEffectView for its HomeScreen Blur effect(above Image)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [control](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView). I think may help you

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

From iOS8, the method you are looking for is `applyLightEffect` which you apply to an image you want to blur.

For more informations, please check out this post from Jeremy Fox:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17138341/1938719

Comment: Actually i want to apply the Blur Effect to my UIVIewController, UIVisualEffectView actually doing this thing right now, but i need to decrease the blur effect(which means i want to see the background Image some more clearly)

Answer (score -1):

You must implement by yourself, and it has spend lot's of time on it.

https://github.com/aaronn/ANBlurredImageView

This item may be help you.

Comment: In iOS8 it's a matter of lines, definitely not very time consuming.

Comment: I Mean, Implement all parts again is more difficult